# Can't reach website on centos 7 anymore

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos-7

I need some help. I have a virtual machine on a server with centos 7. Yesterday everything worked fine until restart and update. Now when I try to reach the website from my pc it says host can't be reached, however I can ping it from my pc. 
Apache is running and I can reach the website from the vm itself. Also there is another weird behaviour since... If I login to centos and fire up the browser, and type in :

- "localhost" does not work (redirects to network's main domain)
- "localhost/index.php" works perfectly
- "127.0.0.0.1" works perfectly

I thought it some dns problem but the host file says only the usual stuff: 127.0.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain..etc.
I checked every single settings I know of but I can't find anywhere mentioned the networks main domain name. I have no idea where that comes from.
And also the website can't be reached from other computer but can be pinged.
The website is empty apache test page now, so nothing in .htaccess
Any idea what else should I check?

Comment: Have you looked at iptables rules and selinux state?

Comment: thank you very much! it was the iptables rules. Its working now. Thanks again!